# Grails application on IE, firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, grails

I have been building and using my grails application for quite a while.
The problem is the application works perfectly on Chrome ( Version 36.0.1985.143 m)

Now, when I run the same app on firefox or IE, I can see the page views but the datasets are not loading and there are multiple errors on the console. 
How do I fix these? Is there something very fundamental that I need to add in my view files 
(HTML)

Errors in IE :

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier 
pagetype, line 1 character 9
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier 
pagetype, line 1 character 9
```

And the error points to the first line 
This is followed by errors in js files and ultimately "dataset" undefined.

Errors in Firefox:

```
ReferenceError: dataset1 is not defined fdd:159
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead d3.v3.min.js:16
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.v3.min.js:13
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead prototype.js:16
TypeError: oa is not a function prototype.js:18447
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead highcharts.js:16
TypeError: oa is not a function highcharts.js:18447
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead exporting.js:16
TypeError: oa is not a function exporting.js:18447
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. d3.v3.min.js:20
```

They are all pointing to the js files used, and I really cannot comprehend the reason for these errors for now.

I really need to understand why the app is not compatible in different browsers, there is something very fundamental I am missing here.Help!

All approaches/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Check where you've defined object literals and make sure there's not a comma after the last item. Also check if you've used a reserved word as an identifier (such as `var class = ...`)

Comment: You may write some test to localize where is your code is broken: on the client or on the server side?